# Check wether a product is configured to be in the parent category or not wihtout using anchor links

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I need to find out all products that are in subcategories but are NOT in their specific parent category. The store I work on cannot use `is Anchor` and the reporting is based on SQL.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT cat.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT( cat.category_id ) , product.sku
FROM catalog_category_product AS cat, catalog_product_entity AS product, catalog_category_entity AS wCat
WHERE cat.product_id = product.entity_id
GROUP BY cat.product_id
```

which selects me all products and their specific SKUs + selected categories.

Next step is to sort out products that are in a parent category AND a child category, which leaves me with a list of Products that are in a child category, but not in a parent category.

Basically:

Show me all products that are in a child-category but NOT in their respective parent category. For example I have a parent ID 2323 in `catalog_category_entity` which is a desired parent category. It has `level` == 2, because 0 is the default category (not visible) and 1 is the first root category (not targeted). Level 2 determines whether a category is a parent category or not.

How would I change my SQL to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
I didn't test it properly but it works for me:

```
SELECT `p`.`entity_id`, `p`.`sku`, `cp`.`category_id` as `category`, `c`.`parent_id` as `parent_category` FROM `catalog_product_entity` as `p`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` as `cp`
ON `p`.`entity_id` = `cp`.`product_id`
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity` as `c`
ON `c`.`entity_id` = `cp`.`category_id`
WHERE `c`.`parent_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `cp1`.`category_id` as `category`
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` as `p1`
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` as `cp1`
    ON `p1`.`entity_id` = `cp1`.`product_id`
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity` as `c1`
    ON `c1`.`entity_id` = `cp1`.`category_id`
    WHERE `p1`.`sku` = `p`.`sku`
)  AND `c`.`parent_id` <> 1
```

Comment: This doesn't really check if a product belongs to a parent category, somehow.

Comment: This match with your direct question:
"Show me all products that are in a child-category but NOT in their respective parent category".
Result of this query gives you list of products that doesn't belong to category and category's parent. If it's not what you looking for - provide deeper explanation...

Comment: Furman, I thank you for your support on this topic. Could you elaborate the AND condition a little bit better? Maybe I simply don't understand it correctly. <> crosschecks for specific values, but as level 2 are parent categories, shouldn't it be "2" instead of "1"?

Comment: Hey man, do you want me to do all works for you? I know it returns duplicate because it's better for testing result. If you want to avoid it - group data or add "DISTINCT" declaration after select...

Comment: No, exactly - 1. It's because all products assigned to category 1 basically. 2-nd category is ROOT - "Default category". So just to avoid returning of all products you need to filter this. "<>" - means NOT EQUAL. 
Sorry for little mess in my explanation. I'm a bit hurry right now. If it's still not clear I can comment all steps little bit later.

Comment: All good, googled stuff up. One thing I'd like to remark is that you do not use c1 anywhere actually, but define it. Also, an INNER JOIN would do the same job with a lower amount of data (thus generating faster => better efficiency). Thanks again, you saved me hours of headache. <3